# Solving a matrix ODE in Matlab

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have a matrix equation in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A(x)\
\end{bmatrix}_{,x}
=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}
A(x)\
\end{bmatrix}^2}{\begin{bmatrix}
B_o\
\end{bmatrix}}
+\begin{bmatrix}
A(x)\
\end{bmatrix} x+\begin{bmatrix}
C_0\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $A$ is a 2*2 matrix, and $B_0$ & $C_0$ are constant 2*2 matrices. I want to integrate it using Matlab, for the period 
$$
x_0<x<x_1
$$
where $A(x_1)$ is known, and I want to find $A(x_0)$

I'm using ode45

> [xx,A_list]=ode45(@(x,A)(A^2/B0+A*x+C0,[x1 x2],A1);

which has always worked for a scaler equation, but I seem to be missing something when integrating matrix equations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that $B^{-1}A^2$ or $A^2B^{-1}$? For matrices these are different, your code computes the second one.

Comment: It is indeed $A^2 B^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a matlab programming problem. `ode45` and all the other solvers only work for flat arrays. You will need to wrap your formula in a duo of reshaping operations.

```
flat2mat=@(A) reshape(A,2,2)
mat2flat=@(A) reshape(A,4,1)
odefunc=@(x,A) A^2/B0+A*x+C0

[xx,A_list]=ode45(@(x,A)mat2flat(odefunc(x,flat2mat(A))),[x1 x2],mat2flat(A1));
```

(untested) should work or at least give more interesting error messages.

Comment: It worked, thank you!